How to fully clean a computer that had been infected, beyond simply reformatting the hard drive?
note: While the bulk of the answers to How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC? involve removing malware from running systems, my question is different.
I will definitely be reformatting the drive and reinstalling a new OS. That's already a given. I will not look for ways to "de-infect" an existing installation.
Instead, I am asking here about other forms of nonvolatile memory in the computer (e.g. the GPU)
I am also asking about overwriting random ones and zeros as part of the reformatting process in order to make sure no traces of malware can be found my new malicious code and reactivated.

We have a DELL Precision T-3600 series computer that the network folks told us was mining bitcoin due to some hacking. It's unknown how bad (i.e. how malicious, pernicious, tenacious, etc.) the hacking was, so we will assume the worst.
We want to reformat the NEO N510+ SSD including overwriting with ones and zeros first, then clean install a different flavor of Linux (I don't know which yet). I opened the box there are no other hard drives (and no DVD in the drive), but there is an NVIDIA T600 GPU which we don't currently use, but may want to experiment with in the future.
For now I plan to pull the GPU out because I don't know if it has any firmware or nonvolatile memory that could have potentially been hacked and now carry something malicious, and we don't need it right now. But I wonder, could it now contain something malicious?
I also don't know how much nonvolatile memory the CPU board or anything else has or whether it has any potential to be hacked.
Besides the reformatting + overwriting and clean install, what else should we do?

It was mining bitcoin because of a malicious infection. The solution to that problem is the same as any malware infection, remove the malware. Your GPU wasn’t hacked. Mining malware is fairly common and honestly isn’t a big deal.

@Ramhound that's how we found out there was something wrong, but we did not do a deep-dive and explore the extent of the compromise or how many there were. We don't know if that was the only problem, or just the latest and most sloppy. With security, I don't understand why "assume the best" would be the wisest choice.

Answers to the duplicate provides excellent advice on how to identify and remove malware

we did not do a deep-dive and explore the extent of the compromise or how many there were IMO that's where it start to lose its sense. I mean, even if all the "nvram/firmware/eeprom infected!" concern could be real, why would you think "a deep clean" would help? And how is it logical that then you ask here "how deep is deep"? Because TBH, regardless of what people tell you, how do/could decide whether it's "yeah that's deep enough" or "no you are just layman go away", when you don't even want to know "how much has happend"? What are you really expecting? A deep clean "suite" (scam)?

Besides, let's say there is some legit "deep clean" you can perform, but how exactly would it actually help when you didn't even know the details of the attack/infection? I mean, you are worried that the cleanse being not deep enough while you are not worried that it is vulnerable / would get dirty again right after the deep clean? No offense but, when I see this kind of "illogical paranoia", I can't help but want to say "*start from scratch with new hardware; and if it happens again, do that again".

@TomYan My question simply asks if I should address it. "Yes or No and here's why" is good Stack Exchange feedback. Suggesting that to ask the question is to be "illogically paranoid" is not. Why the need to take it to the personal level? Grawity's answer is clear, concise and informative when it comes to GPU nonvolatile memory, and doesn't need to resort to "well what's wrong with you"-isms.

@uhoh Well it didn't seem to me that "no and here's why" was/could be "good enough" for you. I'm glad that at least it is now. Still, the "illogical" part I was referring to isn't whether your concern is / could be legit, but the fact that you (seem to) care (only) about the less (or unlikely) problematic part. It's kinda like asking "which firewall is the best one I could buy" while you are going to disable every filter in it.

@TomYan I don't see anything that would indicate whether "no and here's why" was or wasn't good enough for me. The question is only a day old so too early to click accept on an answer, and I've left no comment under the reasonable answer to indicate any view. What I do object to is being called paranoid  and illogically paranoid for simply asking about the non-volatile memory. I did not suggest there was any problem with it, only that I can imagine there might be so I thought I'd ask about it here to get some good advice.


Besides the reformatting + overwriting and clean install, what else should we do?

Nothing.
GPUs do have a lot of firmware, but it is almost always volatile – it's distributed with the OS driver, and the driver needs to upload it to the GPU's RAM on every boot. They also increasingly often enforce digital signature checks (you can mostly thank MPAA for that).
But if it was mining Bitcoin, then it's a fairly safe assumption that the hacking was not a targeted attack, as such attackers would generally try stay below the radar instead of mining Bitcoin, so I wouldn't really worry about GPU firmwares much.
Things like Ethernet interfaces do have non-volatile firmware, on the other hand, as does your computer's mainboard itself – both the system firmware and Intel ME or AMD PSP firmware, for example, though at least the latter is likewise digitally-signed.
Overwriting the SSD multiple times with 1s and 0s is fairly useless. What may be useful against physical data recovery is pointless for virus cleaning, as the OS and CPU will not "see through" overwritten data the way recovery labs might do (which is indeed why recovery labs exist in the first place). From the perspective of the CPU, as soon as a disk sector has been overwritten its data is gone, since it will no longer be returned by READ operations, so it cannot influence the host PC in any way. So just zero it out once, or use the SATA or NVMe "secure erase" command – and it should be fine.

Thanks for your answer! The bitcoin mining may be only the latest attack rather than the only attack. It's good to know that the GPU is not likely to have firmware in nonvolatile memory, but I'll probably try to double check that for the T600 somewhere. Just fyi for future readers, PC magazine, July 26, 2022 Malware That Can Survive OS Reinstalls Found On Asus, Gigabyte Motherboards (found here)

Just wipe the machine and move on with life.
There are no risks of malware being somehow embedded in nonvolatile components. Just wipe the machine and move on with life.

“note: While the bulk of the answers to How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC? involve removing malware from running systems, my question is different.”

This is not at all substantially different. You are fabricating scenarios that just don’t exist:

“I also don't know how much nonvolatile memory the CPU board or anything else has or whether it has any potential to be hacked.”

There is no risk to the CPU, CPU or RAM. None at all. Just wipe the machine and move on with life.

“For now I plan to pull the GPU out because I don't know if it has any firmware or nonvolatile memory that could have potentially been hacked and now carry something malicious, and we don't need it right now.”

Utter paranoia. Just wipe the machine and move on with life.
Also, this…

“I am also asking about overwriting random ones and zeros as part of the reformatting process in order to make sure no traces of malware can be found my new malicious code and reactivated.”

If it is an SSD, that level of erasure is not needed. If it is a hard drive, maybe that would help. But mainly it will just give you a better level of confidence in the process. The risk of “zombie” malware springing to life from an erased storage device doesn’t exist. Even just wiping out the drive with a basic “zero-writing” erase is a bit of overkill.
